# How to add image before text on every line in PDF?

Tags: c#, itext

I need to add an image to every single line in my PDF.  At the moment I am getting this:

```
Rectangle: 16x16 (rot: 0 degrees)Domain\administrator [Allow] 
Rectangle: 16x16 (rot: 0 degrees)Domain\User1 [Allow]
Rectangle: 16x16 (rot: 0 degrees)Domain\User2 [Allow]
```

My app searches directories and display's user rights to the folders searched
It saves it to a text file where I then red from the text file and add to my PDF

```
var image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Resources.user, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
List<string> dirf = new List<string>();
                        try
                        {
                            foreach (string dirfo in Directory.GetDirectories(location))
                            {
                                foldersCounted++;
                                document.Add(new LineSeparator(0.5f, 100, null, 0, -5));
                                document.Add(new Paragraph(dirfo, font6));
                                string seperator = csvPermissions.Replace(", ", "\n" + image1);
                                document.Add(new Paragraph(seperator, font5));
                                document.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
                                document.Add(new LineSeparator(0.5f, 100, null, 0, -5));
```

In this line `string seperator = csvPermissions.Replace(", ", "\n" + image1);`
I have added the `image1`  and as you can see it outputs `Rectangle: 16x16 (rot: 0 degrees)`

I would like to have the image (which is a user icon) display next to each line showing user rights

Just wondering if this is possible and if so how can I achieve that?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is what it gives me now:

```
`image`
     text text text text text
     text text text text text
     text text text text text
```

I would like to show:

```
 image text text text text
 image text text text text
 image text text text text
```

Comment: Suggestion: have you considered adding your images to Paragraph: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118224/itext-adding-external-image-using-chunk

Comment: Hi,  I did look at that but it does not work.  it puts the image at top and then the the text starts underneath.  Please see edit in question

Comment: I don't know if maybe because from the text file all text is in one line and separated by a `,` and then in my PDF I replace that `,` with `\n`.  So maybe the PDF is seeing it as a complete paragraph instead of one line?